# GET request in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

On my front end, I'm using this link with axios with a placeID parameter: http://localhost:3001/api/getData?placeID=Uh8LPCRstLnJ-ZY3B41N9w

I basically want to get all results where the placeID equals something. So in mySQL Select * From reviews Where placeID=***. Right now I'm getting a 404 not found and I've made sure that there is something in the database with the specific placeID. What am I doing wrong in this get request?

Here is what it looks like in the back end

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const express = require("express");
var cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const logger = require("morgan");
const Data = require("./data");

const API_PORT = 3001;
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const router = express.Router();

// this is our MongoDB database
const dbRoute =
  "mongodb+srv://name:pass@cluster0-p8ar4.mongodb.net/reviews?retryWrites=true";

// connects our back end code with the database
mongoose.connect(dbRoute, { useNewUrlParser: true });

let db = mongoose.connection;

db.once("open", () => console.log("connected to the database"));

// checks if connection with the database is successful
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB connection error:"));

// (optional) only made for logging and
// bodyParser, parses the request body to be a readable json format
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(logger("dev"));

// this is our get method
// this method fetches all available data in our database

router.get("/getData/:placeID", (req, res) => {
  const { placeID } = req.params.placeID;
  Data.find({ placeID: placeID }, function(err, data) {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
    return res.json({ success: true, data: data });
  });
});

// launch our backend into a port
app.listen(API_PORT, () => console.log(`LISTENING ON PORT ${API_PORT}`));
```

Here is the schema in the data.js file

```
// /backend/data.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// this will be our data base's data structure
const DataSchema = new Schema(
  {
    placeID: String,
    seatRating: Number,
    comfortRating: Number,
    internetRating: Number,
    noiseRating: Number,
    outletRating: Number
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

// export the new Schema so we could modify it using Node.js
module.exports = mongoose.model("Data", DataSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`router.get("/getData/:placeID"` means placeID is used exactly like you specified, not as a parameter, but like a path, `404` is an HTTP code and not a mongodb code, that's the first hint that you're doing something wrong in accessing the correct path, accessing `http://localhost:3001/api/getData/Uh8LPCRstLnJ-ZY3B41N9w` should fix it

Do you see we passed the id like we do with `parameters` and `arguments` ? now in express `req.params.placeID` will be `Uh8LPCRstLnJ-ZY3B41N9w`